# MPI_Bcast into a while loop

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "mpi.h"

struct fields{
  int hostNumber;
  int *numberArray;
}; 

struct fields *start(int);
struct fields *gatherData(int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size, count, *tmpArray, tmpNumOfArray;
     
    struct fields *myFields;      
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);        
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);        
   
    while(1){            
        if (rank == 0){
            //printf("I am parent-process with rank = %d, size = %d\n", rank, size);
                     
            myFields = start(rank);
            //for (int i = 0 ; i < myFields->hostNumber ; i++) printf("%d\n",((myFields->numberArray)[i]));
                           
            if ((myFields->hostNumber) < size){
                printf("Error!!! Number of Processes is more than number of Elements.\n");
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);  
            }

            if ((myFields->hostNumber) < (2 * size)){
                printf("Error!!! The Host of Numbers should be at least double of the number  of Processes!!!\n");
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);  
            }
      
            tmpNumOfArray = myFields->hostNumber;
            MPI_Bcast(&tmpNumOfArray, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);            
        printf("process = %d, tmpNumOfArray = %d\n", rank, tmpNumOfArray);
        sleep(5);    
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0;
}

struct fields *start(int rank){
  int input;
  struct fields *myFields;
  system("clear");
  printf("1) Type 1 For Execution\n");
  printf("2) Type 2 For Exit\n");
  printf("Give your choice:");     
  scanf("%d",&input);

  switch(input){
    case 1:
        myFields = gatherData(rank);
        break;
    case 2:
    default:
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0); 
}
  return myFields;
}

struct fields *gatherData(int rank){
int host;
struct fields *myFields;

myFields = (struct fields *)malloc(sizeof(struct fields));    
if (myFields == NULL){
    printf("Cannot allocate memory for myFields struct!\n");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);     
}

if (rank == 0){
    printf("Give the host of the numbers to be statically checked: ");
    scanf("%d",&host);

    int *nmbArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(nmbArray) * host);   
    for (int i = 0; i < host; i++){
        printf("Give the %d number:", i);
        scanf("%d", (&(nmbArray[i])));
    }  
    
    myFields->hostNumber = host;
    myFields->numberArray = &nmbArray[0];
}
  return myFields;      
}
```

When I run it I get the followng:

```
process = 2, tmpNumOfArray = 0
process = 0, tmpNumOfArray = 10
process = 1, tmpNumOfArray = 0
process = 3, tmpNumOfArray = 0
```

And what I what is:

```
process = 2, tmpNumOfArray = 10
process = 0, tmpNumOfArray = 10
process = 1, tmpNumOfArray = 10
process = 3, tmpNumOfArray = 10
```

Any suggestion? Do not concentrate on `gatherData()` and `start()` functions since they run perfectly, the problem it at main() down to the MPI_Bcast() function. Also I tried with MPI_COMM_SPAWN but I think it can't broadcast from parent to children.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

**[MPI_Bcast](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Bcast.html)**

> Broadcasts a message from the process with rank "root" to all other
> processes of the communicator

The `MPI_Bcast` broadcast routine is collective communication. [Hence](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-broadcast-and-collective-communication/):

> Collective communication is a method of communication which involves
> participation of all processes in a communicator.

The problem with your code is that only process with `rank=0` is calling the `MPI_Bcast`; instead all the processes involved should also call that MPI routine.

Fix you code by moving that call accordingly, namely:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "mpi.h"

struct fields{
  int hostNumber;
  int *numberArray;
}; 

struct fields *start(int);
struct fields *gatherData(int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank, size, count, *tmpArray, tmpNumOfArray;
     
    struct fields *myFields;      
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);        
    
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);        
   
    while(1){            
        if (rank == 0)
        {          
            myFields = start(rank);
            if ((myFields->hostNumber) < size){
                printf("Error!!! Number of Processes is more than number of Elements.\n");
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);  
            }

            if ((myFields->hostNumber) < (2 * size)){
                printf("Error!!! The Host of Numbers should be at least double of the number  of Processes!!!\n");
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);  
            }
            tmpNumOfArray = myFields->hostNumber;
        }
        
        MPI_Bcast(&tmpNumOfArray, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Move this part
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);            
        printf("process = %d, tmpNumOfArray = %d\n", rank, tmpNumOfArray);
        sleep(5); 
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0;
}

struct fields *start(int rank){
  int input;
  struct fields *myFields;
  system("clear");
  printf("1) Type 1 For Execution\n");
  printf("2) Type 2 For Exit\n");
  printf("Give your choice:");     
  scanf("%d",&input);

  switch(input){
    case 1:
        myFields = gatherData(rank);
        break;
    case 2:
    default:
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0); 
  }
  return myFields;
}

struct fields *gatherData(int rank){
int host;
struct fields *myFields;

myFields = (struct fields *)malloc(sizeof(struct fields));    
if (myFields == NULL){
    printf("Cannot allocate memory for myFields struct!\n");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0);     
}

if (rank == 0){
    printf("Give the host of the numbers to be statically checked: ");
    scanf("%d",&host);

    int *nmbArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(nmbArray) * host);   
    for (int i = 0; i < host; i++){
        printf("Give the %d number:", i);
        scanf("%d", (&(nmbArray[i])));
    }  
    
    myFields->hostNumber = host;
    myFields->numberArray = &nmbArray[0];
}
  return myFields;      
}
```

Comment: yes you are right but think that i tried it and didn't work, now it's ok. thanks.